# Spark sql DATEADD

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to filter out data from the current date to last 3 years and trying to use this for spark sql query: (eg : `d_date` column format `2009-09-18`
)

```sql
WHERE d_date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())
```

But getting following error.

> Undefined function: 'DATEADD'. This function is neither a registered
> temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database
> 'default'.;

Is there any DATEADD equivalent for spark SQL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spark SQL has [`date_add`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/search.html?q=date_add) function and it's different from the one you're trying to use as it takes only a number of days to add.

For your case you can use [`add_months`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#add_months) to add `-36 = 3 years`

```sql
WHERE d_date >= add_months(current_date(), -36)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to blackbishop's answer above, it's `add_months` if you're running Azure Data Bricks.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/functions/add_months